# Kuberntes/Prometheus - Unable to Annotate in service file

Tags: annotations, kubernetes, prometheus

My Kubernetes version is :

```
# kubectl --version
Kubernetes v1.4.0
```

I am planning to use Prometheus to monitor my Kube cluster. For this, I need to annotate the metrics URL.

My current metrics URL is like :

```
http://172.16.33.7:8080/metrics
```

But I want it to be like :

```
http://172.16.33.7:8080/websocket/metrics
```

First I tried to do this manually ::

```
kubectl annotate pods websocket-backend-controller-db83999c5b534b277b82badf6c152cb9m1 prometheus.io/path=/websocket/metrics
kubectl annotate pods websocket-backend-controller-db83999c5b534b277b82badf6c152cb9m1 prometheus.io/scrape='true'
kubectl annotate pods websocket-backend-controller-db83999c5b534b277b82badf6c152cb9m1 prometheus.io/port='8080'
```

All these commands work perfectly fine and I am able to see the annotations.

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "websocket-backend-controller-v1krf",
    "generateName": "websocket-backend-controller-",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/websocket-backend-controller-v1krf",
    "uid": "e323994b-4081-11e7-8bd0-0050569b6f44",
    "resourceVersion": "27534379",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-05-24T13:07:06Z",
    "labels": {
      "name": "websocket-backend"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicationController\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"websocket-backend-controller\",\"uid\":\"e321f1a8-4081-11e7-8bd0-0050569b6f44\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"resourceVersion\":\"27531840\"}}\n",
      "prometheus.io/path": "/websocket/metrics",
      "prometheus.io/port": "8080",
      "prometheus.io/scrape": "true"
    }
```

But since I want this configuration to remain permanent, I am setting the following annotations in my services files.

```
# cat websocket-service.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websocket-service
  labels:
    baseApi: websocket
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/path: /websocket/metrics
    prometheus.io/port: '8080'
spec:
  selector:
    name: websocket-backend
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30800
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  clusterIP: 10.100.10.45
```

I restarted my websocket service and the corresponding pods but these configs do not seem to be taking effect.

```
kubectl create -f websocket-service.yaml
kubectl create -f ../controllers/websocket-replication-controller.yaml
```

The result does not show the annotations configured.

```
{
      "metadata": {
        "name": "websocket-backend-controller-v1krf",
        "generateName": "websocket-backend-controller-",
        "namespace": "default",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/websocket-backend-controller-v1krf",
        "uid": "e323994b-4081-11e7-8bd0-0050569b6f44",
        "resourceVersion": "27531879",
        "creationTimestamp": "2017-05-24T13:07:06Z",
        "labels": {
          "name": "websocket-backend"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicationController\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"websocket-backend-controller\",\"uid\":\"e321f1a8-4081-11e7-8bd0-0050569b6f44\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"resourceVersion\":\"27531840\"}}\n"
        }
```

All I am doing is rather than using a command line, I am setting the configs using services config but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you annotate the service, it doesn't take any effect on the possibly matched pods. Your pods are managed either by a ReplicationController, or over a ReplicaSet / Deployment. In that case, annotate these resources to make the annotations reach the pods. In example of deployments, you must use the template section, like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Unique key of the Deployment instance
  name: deployment-example
spec:
  # 3 Pods should exist at all times.
  replicas: 3
  # Keep record of 2 revisions for rollback
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/path: /websocket/metrics
        prometheus.io/port: '8080'
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have been looking around for how to pass annotations from deployment to pods for days!